# How should I localise with multiple parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, localization

Let's say I have the following string:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Booked for %@ at %@", colleagueName, time];
```

And I realise I've forgotten to localise that string, so I replace it:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"bookings.bookedFor", "Booked for user at time"), colleagueName, time];
```

---

Now when doing translations, I find that the language X needs the parameters the other way round; something closer to:

```
<time> for booking of <colleague> is done.
```

What is the best way to address the fact that now I need the second parameter of my formatted string to be `time` and the third to be `colleagueName` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, my colleague found the solution almost as soon as I had asked on here! Apparently Objective-C has positional arguments

The positions are 1-indexed so `%1$@` refers to the first argument.

```
NSString *firstParam = @"1st";
NSString *secondParam = @"2nd";
NSLog(@"First %1$@ Second: %2$@", firstParam, secondParam);
NSLog(@"Second %2$@ First: %1$@", firstParam, secondParam);
```

---

This prints:

```
First 1st Second: 2nd   
Second 2nd First: 1st
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this:

```
    NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([language isEqualToString:@"X"]) {//X is language code like "fr","de"
      [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"bookings.bookedFor", "Booked for user at time"), time, colleagueName];
    } else {
      [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"bookings.bookedFor", "Booked for user at time"), colleagueName,time];
    }
```